Cyrillic characters wont show up in console
So, only characters that I input shows perfectly fine, but the output characters (when im doing Console.WriteLine) change to '?' Output
It is weird because before every cyrillic character was showing up
I tried adding Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8, ASCII, Unicode and others, nothing works.

Which framework your app targeted on? If it is .NET (Core), not .NET Framework, you should register encoding provider before setting Console output encoding. Add this line before: Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);

Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please  open [Help] and read at least [ask]. Then, [edit] your question to share a [mcve].

Try to move Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8 before builder.Build() (If you use WebApplication builder).
